# How to center Inline-block elements horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 bootstrap buttons. I want them to be in-line and centered horizontally. Here is the html( it looks complicated, but it's really repetetive):

```
    <div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ]">
        <div class="[ form-group ]">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-success-custom-icons" id="fancy-checkbox-success-custom-icons" autocomplete="off" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-success-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-success ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-plus ]"></span>
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-minus ]"></span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-success-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                    Nature
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="[ form-group ]">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info-custom-icons" id="fancy-checkbox-info-custom-icons" autocomplete="off" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-info-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-plus ]"></span>
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-minus ]"></span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-info-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                    History
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="[ form-group ]">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-warning-custom-icons" id="fancy-checkbox-warning-custom-icons" autocomplete="off" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-warning-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-warning ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-plus ]"></span>
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-minus ]"></span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-warning-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                    Architecture
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="[ form-group ]">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-danger-custom-icons" id="fancy-checkbox-danger-custom-icons" autocomplete="off" />
            <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-danger-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-danger ]">
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-plus ]"></span>
                    <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-minus ]"></span>
                </label>
                <label for="fancy-checkbox-danger-custom-icons" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                    Entertainment
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

They have their css:

```
.form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span {
    width: 20px;
}

.form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
    display: none;
}
.form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;

}

.form-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is show those 4 buttons in-line and center them horizontally. Why is this not working:

```
.form-group{
    display: inline;

}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why the brackets in class attributes?

Comment: add the text-align: center on the parent container class.

Comment: @ZimSystem, I was asking myself the same thing so I wrote a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaRpdv) to test it. It works but of course it will add the `[` and `]` classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center those `.form-group` elements, change the outer parent...

```
<div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ]">
```

to

```
<div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ] text-center">
```

the `.text-center` class will assign `text-align: center` to an element, and that CSS will center `inline` or `inline-block` children.

Comment: Logical answer, but somehow it didn't work. All it did was pushed buttons to right for like a quarter of the screen. Not a centre

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis It's because `.col-sm-6` is `width: 50%;` so that column only takes up half the screen. Remove all of those classes and only use `.text-center` if you want it to take up the width of the screen and the buttons to be centered, so the div looks like `<div class="text-center">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ]">
```

should be changed to

```
<div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center]">
```

Because I believe "col-sm-6" will take up to half of the screen.